# Best practice for handling service configuration in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to deploy a docker application in a production environment (single host) using a docker-compose file provided by the application creator. The docker based solution is being used as a drop-in replacement for a monolithic binary installer.

The application ships with a default configuration but with an expectation that the administrator will want to apply moderate configuration changes.

There appears to be a few ways to apply custom configuration to the services that are defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file however I am not sure which is considered best practice. The two I am considering between at the moment are:

- **Bake the configuration into a new image**. Here, I would add a build step for each service defined in the docker-compose file and create a minimal `Dockerfile` which uses `COPY` to replace the existing configuration files in the image with my custom config files. Using `sed` and `echo` in `CMD` statements could also be used to change configuration inline without replacing the files wholesale.
- **Use a bind mount with configuration stored on the host**. In this case, I would store all custom configuration files in a directory on the host machine and define bind mounts in the `volumes` parameter for each service in the docker-compose file.

The first option seems the cleanest to me as the application is completely self-contained, however I would need to rebuild the image if I wanted to make any further configuration changes. The second option seems the easiest as I can make configuration changes on the fly (restarting services as required in the container).

Is there a recommended method for injecting custom configuration into Docker services?

Answer (score 3):

Given your context, I think using a bind mount would be better.

A Docker image is supposed to be reusable in different context, and building an entire image solely for a specific configuration (i.e. environment) would defeat that purpose:

- instead of the generic configuration provided by the base image, you create an environment-specific image
- everytime you need to change the configuration you'll need to rebuild the entire image, whereas with a bind mount a simple restart or re-read of the configuration file by application will be sufficient
- Docker documentation recommend that:

  [Dockerfile best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#volume)

  > You are strongly encouraged to use VOLUME for any **mutable and/or
  >   user-serviceable parts of your image.**

  [Good use cases for bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#good-use-cases-for-bind-mounts)

  > Sharing **configuration files** from the host machine to containers.

Comment: I'd suggest never using `VOLUME` in a Dockerfile unless you're absolutely clear on what it does; it is not required for bind-mounting config files to work.